# Errata for Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning?

Tags: reference-request, proof-verification

I'm new here, so I hope this is the right place to post this!

I am currently reading through the Dover edition of the textbook **Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning**, by Aleksandrov, Kolmogorov, and Lavrent'ev.

So here is my dilemma: I think that I've come across a couple errors, so far, in the second chapter, but I can't be sure because I haven't been able to find an existing compilation of Errata! (UGH!). Obviously I'd like to be sure, since if they aren't actual errors, then that must mean I am misunderstanding something.

The book itself was written in the 50's and translated in the 60's.  Amazon says my version was published in 1999, but the inside page says that my copy was manufactured in 2014.  Considering how old this book is I feel certain that here has to be either: an existing Errata page, or no errors. So my question is, does anyone have the Errata for this book, or know where I can find it?

Thank you very sincerely for your time.

Best regards,

Baer

**Edit:** Here is a link to a pdf of chapter 2:
http://www.ees.nmt.edu/outside/courses/hyd510/PDFs/SupplementaryReadings/Mathematics_its%20content,%20methods,%20and%20meaning.pdf

The errors I think I found are below. It would be great if someone could even just take a minute to confirm whether or not I've actually found errors! Please help!

---

Pg. 103, volume 1:

Here is the equation taken from the book..
$$ \frac{Δy}{Δx} = \frac{v \frac{Δy}{Δx} - u \frac{Δv}{Δx}}{v + Δv} $$
which is explaining the quotient rule. But shouldn't it actually be...
$$ \frac{Δy}{Δx} = \frac{v \frac{Δu}{Δx} - u \frac{Δv}{Δx}}{v + Δv} $$
replacing Δy with Δu in the first nested fraction?

---

Pg. 107, volume 1:

Shouldn't this equation explaining the chain rule... $$y_x' = y_u' * u_x$$ actually be replaced with this? $$y_x' = y_u' * u_x'$$

---

Pg. 112, volume 1:

Here it claims that the function $$ y=e^{-x^2} $$ attains it's maximum at the point x = 1. But shouldn't that actually be at the point x = 0?

Comment: That "feature" has driven away at least one very gifted community member.  Still, this would be more valuable as an Edit to the Question.  There is [an introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) with $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Fixed! I edited the (suspected) errors into the original post.

Comment: Book reviews often mention errata. Here are two that I know of, although I don't know if either mentions any errata because I don't have access to them -- they are not freely available on the internet, but if you have access to a university library you should be able to look them up: Hubert Edwin Chrestenson, Burrowes Hunt, and Joseph [Joe] Buffington Roberts, American Mathematical Monthly 73 #8 (October 1966), pp. 913-914 **AND** Leslie Frank Newbold, Mathematical Gazette 52 #382 (December 1968), p. 395.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematics-its-content-methods-and-meaning

This one should be ok, I've read it and I didn't find any.

Comment: That's actually the same version I have.

Comment: okay, then I probably missed it out

Comment: no problem. I just edited in the suspected errors, if you wanted to take a look at them.